# Comando exec abre o ficheiro no Internet explorer em vez de abrir o comando numa nova aba do Chrome

Tags: php

Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o exec() abra um ficheiro pdf num navegador diferente do definido por padrão sem ter de modificar este ultimo?

O meu objetivo é fazer com que o exec abra o pdf especificamente numa nova aba do chrome em vez de abrir uma nova janela no navegador predifinido.

(Não tem necessariamente de ser no chrome mas sim no navegador em que o utilizador esta a usar a aplicação)

Answer (score 1):

Creio que com o php não tem jeito, pois ele fica no servidor e não saberia qual o navegador o cliente está usando. Talvez utilizando javascript. Segue um exemplo do código para ver se lhe ajuda:
`window.open('/arquivo/teste.pdf');`